# Swift: Using Protocols to create private class instance

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, private

I am really new to Swift, and trying to understand how to work things out with protocol extensions. So here is my protocol:

```
public protocol User: class {
    var name : String {get}
}
private class MyUser: User {
    var name : String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
extension User where Self:User {
    func createUser(name: String) -> User {
        return MyUser(name)
    }
}
```

How do I call this function `createUser` from a totally different class/protocol, where I want to create an instance of User?

Answer (score -1):

You could remake the function in whatever class you need it for

```
func createUser(name: String) -> User {
      return MyUser(name)
}
```

then say

```
let newUser = createUser("WhateverName")
```

or you could do:

```
let newUser = User().createUser("WhateverName")
```